# Integrating spring with cassandra using Hector

Tags: spring, cassandra, hector

I am working on a `Spring` application and need to talk to `Cassandra` using `Hector`. Need some help as to how to approach. I want to use `JPA` and utilise the dependency injection features of Spring too.

Any points help!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Hi I tried to integrate my Spring MVC project with my local Cassandra DB .Have Configured the POM.xml and got the required dependencies.The Dal layer is complete. I am facing two issues 1.How can I make queries as  I need to fetch data from more than one column Families.2)How to go about indexing the columns for Querying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JPA compliance i have used Kundera,I could integrate it with spring very easily and Yes  as Hardik Bhalani has suggested the columnfamilies were designed carefully to achieve maximum efficiency

Answer (score 1):

answer to your 1st issue : You have to desing and normalize your data model so that it can reduce traversal among multiple column family . For e.g. if you are storing some user id in CF itemlist you should insert user's JSON object having use details instead of that userid , by this way at the time of fetching traversal to the usermaster CF can be avoided

Comment: Which issue are you answering? Does your advice assist in having a Spring-Cassandra-Hector or is it in regard to JPA. I haven't worked with JPA and Spring-Hector-Cassandra yet.

Comment: my answer points to the solution of "How can I make queries as I need to fetch data from more than one column Families"
my solution to this is try to design data model so that it requires less dependency as explained in my example

Comment: well I am into Production now with my code.I used Kundera + SPrings.Yes as Hardik Bhalani has suggested the columnfamilies were designed carefully to achieve maximum efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do get it done pretty easily using this [documentation](http://hector-client.github.io/hector/build/html/content/spring_dependency_injection.html), but this leaves you with SimpleCassandraDao (which you can inject to your DAO) - which is quite limited.

What I did was creating the connection pragmatically:

```
@PostConstruct
public void connect() {
if (Boolean.parseBoolean(isActive)) {
    CassandraHostConfigurator cassandraHostConfigurator = new CassandraHostConfigurator(this.socket);
    cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster(clusterName, cassandraHostConfigurator);
    ConfigurableConsistencyLevel consistencyLevelPolicy = new ConfigurableConsistencyLevel();
    consistencyLevelPolicy.setDefaultReadConsistencyLevel(getConsistencyLevelPolicy());
    keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace(keyspaceName, cluster, consistencyLevelPolicy);
    if (isConnected())
    fireConnectionEvent(true);
    else {
    LOG.error("Could not connect to socket " + this.socket + ". Connection to Cassandra DB is down!!!");
    }
} else {
    LOG.info("Cassandra connection is not active hence could not connect to socket " + this.socket
        + ". Please activate the connection before trying to connect");
}
}
```

This method is a part of a spring bean (annotated with the *Component* annotation), so once the application is deployed the connection pool is created.
As you see, I'm firing a connection-event (using [Spring Application-Event](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.M2/reference/html/applicationevent.html) support).The event holds the newly created keyspace then catched by my Dao. This way, my Dao can initialize the required queries. for instance:

```
StringSerializer stringSerializer = StringSerializer.get();
SliceQuery<String, String, String> query = HFactory.createSliceQuery(this.keyspace, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, stringSerializer)
        .setColumnFamily(columnFamily).setRange(null, null, false, 4).setKey(rowKey);

    ColumnSlice<String, String> columnsSlice = query.execute().get();
    List<HColumn<String, String>> columns = columnsSlice.getColumns();
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Playorm which 1. supports sql like joins for two columnfamilies 2. Provides indexing support on columns too.